# How can I embed watermark in an image after using Hough Transform?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, watermark, hough-transform

I am trying to do image watermarking using Hough Transform for my university project. I took an image and transformed it with Hough Transform.

Now, How can I add some hidden data or watermark this transformed image and embed it? Is it possible using only Hough Transform or I need to use another matrix decomposition?

Comment: posting some code will be useful to be able to suggest solutions.

Comment: I just did Hough transform on an image in Matlab, nothing more. In output, I got the Hough matrix.

Comment: Why do you want to focus on using the Hough transform? There are better methods for embedding watermarks that are proven to work.

Comment: My project teacher wants me to use a less usable method. For that, I choose Hough. But now I find it hard to embed watermark in it.

Comment: Can you say, is it possible to do watermark with Hough Transform? If not, then I have to try another transformation.